# How to push to gitlab with java api with ssh

Tags: git, jgit, java

I am using gitlab of version GitLab Community Edition 9.1.1 d3123f6.

I am able to push my code to gitlab with http protocol but when I am trying with git protocol it is showing following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: 
ssh://git@192......: 
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialItem$YesNoType:The authenticity 
of host '192......' can't be established.

RSA key fingerprint is 
99:...............
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.get(UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialsProviderUserInfo.promptYesNo(CredentialsProviderUserInfo.java:124)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:785)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1201)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:136)
at org.dstadler.jgit.unfinished.PushToRemoteRepository.main(PushToRemoteRepository.java:100)
```

and my code is

```
private static final String REMOTE_URL = "git@192.....:ash/test.git";
File localPath = new File("/home/user/Git", "");
localPath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
localPath.createNewFile();
if(!localPath.delete()) {
    throw new IOException("Could not delete temporary file " + localPath);
}

Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI( REMOTE_URL )
        .setDirectory(localPath)
        .setCredentialsProvider( cp )
        .call();
System.out.println("Cloning from " + REMOTE_URL + " to " + localPath);


System.out.println("please edit the file and then press \"Enter\" here to push ");
System.in.read();


File file = new File( git.getRepository().getWorkTree(), "file" + new Object().hashCode() );

git.add().addFilepattern( file.getName() ).call();

git.commit().setAll(true).setMessage("a message").call();

git.push() .setCredentialsProvider( cp ) .call();

System.out.println("Pushed from repository: " + localPath + " to remote repository at " + REMOTE_URL);
```

Comment: i think REMOTE_URL is not correct

Comment: but I copied that from gitlab itself..do I need to change something? @ArvindDhakad

Comment: I tried to add ssh://git@192.....  `NotSupportedException: URI not supported: ssh:///git@192`

Comment: this is not valid server url

Comment: remote url should be a valid server URL

Comment: will you please provide an example of ssh url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to establish a connection from command line first:

```
ssh git@...
```

That should ask you the same question: answer 'y'.

Once that is done, meaning once the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` has been updated by the key scan of the remote server, you can try your same Java JGit program again.

I posted before (5 years ago) [a solution, but for EGit, not JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209038/6309).

See more at "[JGit Authentication Explained](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/)"

> JGit provides an abstract [JSchConfigSessionFactory](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=JSchConfigSessionFactory%20&type=) that uses JSch to establish SSH connections and requires its `configure()` to be overridden

The [OP Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7997976/ash) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346552/how-to-push-to-gitlab-with-java-api-with-ssh/44348972#comment75923373_44348972):

> The problem was in `.ssh/config` file where needed lines are commented including private key identity.

Comment: I tried the same steps still it is showing same error, my code looks like this  `private static final String REMOTE_URL = "git@192.16...1..1..:ashwath/test.git";

    static SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void configure( Host host, Session session ) {
          // do nothing
        }
      };`

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
        
        UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("ashwath", "abcd");
        
        CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository();

        cloneCommand.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback(){
        @Override
          public void configure( Transport transport ) {
            SshTransport sshTransport = ( SshTransport )transport;
            sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory( sshSessionFactory );
          }
        } );`

Comment: I am able to do the same in command prompt, yes it was asking to type yes or no first time..I wonder what can be the error?

Comment: But first, did you do the manual step `ssh git@...`? Do you see a `~/.ssh/known_hosts` updated?

Comment: yes when I run that command it is showing `/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts: line 1: `|1|6GHFDDs4eE+Tj6t+8FBeYVQwaGo=|CHLmBzUxFKYIGpiUNv1KBYsIgNc= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIb........`

Comment: @Ash then rename that `/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts`, and try again the ssh command: it will recreate it.

Comment: I can do git clone git@192....but if I do ssh git@192.169.1.:ashwath./test.git  It is showing "could not resolve host name 192.... name or service not known

Comment: @Ash Yes, the ssh command to do is only the first part: `ssh git@192...` (without `:xxx`): it is only to be done one time, to update the `known_hosts` file. After that, as long as your Java program is executed with the same user account, it should reuse the information set in `known_hosts`.

Comment: @Ash So , no more syntax error? Now, your java program should work, at at the very least, not trigger the same `The authenticity of host` error message.

Comment: @Ash If it still does, set that known_host file for JSch used by JGit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15645473/6309

Comment: I am getting error  unknown host key..rsa finger print is 99:4f......the finger print which I copied to gitlab is 19:7c...... should both match?

Comment: @Ash they should match yes.

Comment: The problem was in ssh.config file where needed lines are commented including private key identity:)

Comment: @Ash OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.